# How do I set the iTerm2 session title through escape codes?

Tags: shell, iterm2, iterm

The [iTerm2 page on badges](https://iterm2.com/documentation-badges.html) mentions that session.name can be changed with escape codes, but describes the method somewhat cryptically:

> ***session.name***
>
> The current session's name. Defaults to the profile name. May be changed with the escape sequence **OSC 1 ; name ST**, or by editing the session title in **View>Edit Current Session**.

If you look further down the page at code describing how to change badges, we see a sort of Rosetta Store:

> The badge itself may be set with the following escape sequence:
>
> `OSC 1337 ; SetBadgeFormat=Base-64 encoded badge format ST`
>
> Here's an example that works in bash:
>
> ```
>  # Set badge to show the current session name and git branch, if any is set.
>  printf "\e]1337;SetBadgeFormat=%s\a" \
>  $(echo -n "\(session.name) \(user.gitBranch)" | base64)
> ```

We can infer from this that "OSC" is meant to stand in for "\e]" and "ST" for "\a".  But even with that information, nothing works:

```
printf "\e]1;%s\a" "New Title"
echo -en "\e]1;New Title\a"
```

(If you know how to set the tab title, that's also of interest to me!  But I don't see any indication that it's possible to do through escape codes.)

Comment: Try \e\\ (Esc, backslash) instead of `\a` - the former is a version of ST per https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/chapter4.html , Tables 4-2 and 4-3.  OSC and ST are vt100 control codes.

Comment: The issue might be that it's broken in the latest beta: Build 3.3.0beta6

Answer (score 0):

iTerm OSC 1337 proprietary codes end with ^G (BEL, or ASCII 7). The documentation may be broken. Try adding one at the end.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, you can echo escape characters like

```
echo -e "\033\];new title\a"
```

which will result in the tab title change, for example:

[image]

This is working for iterm2, Build 3.4.19

Comment: I just tried that in Build 3.5.0beta10, and it failed for me, giving an audible and visible beep, and printing `];new title` on the line below the prompt.  I'm using zsh too. (I don't know if there are any relevant settings that might be different in my shell.)

Comment: hmm -- there are so many preferences in iterm2! My shell is "zsh", character encoding is UTF-8; terminal type is "xterm-256color".  There are more example escape sequences at https://iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html

Comment: that page mentions that some things break inside tmux and screen, so maybe some of my iTerm preferences related to tmux break it even when I don't have tmux running 

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of names: icon name and window title. Window title is the one on the title bar, icon name is that on the tab. set them to your liking.

See Thomas Dickey's escape sequences page [here](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#:%7E:text=%3B%20Pt%20BEL-,OSC%20Ps%20%3B%20Pt%20ST,-Set%20Text%20Parameters).

You can use `echo -en '\e]1;TITLEHERE\e\\'` to set icon name,
`echo -en '\e]2;TITLEHERE\e\\'` to set window title,
and `echo -en '\e]0;TITLEHERE\e\\'` to set both.